# javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus() not found

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am working with an embedded Jetty server, deploying a Jersey REST api, and I am trying to log the errors, with log4J. When an error happens, for instance a URL not found, and the console log shows the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.callSendError(ResponseWriter.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.commit(ResponseWriter.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:413)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.release(ServerRuntime.java:810)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

There are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m09</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And the server initialization code:

```
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
resourceConfig.register(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);
resourceConfig.register(PrivateAPI.class);
resourceConfig.register(MalformedURLExceptionMapper.class);
ServletContainer sc = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(sc);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(holder, "/*");


Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])));
HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();

handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {servletContextHandler, new RequestLogHandler(), new DefaultHandler()});
server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError while calling response.getStatus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257459/nosuchmethoderror-while-calling-response-getstatus)

Answer (score 18):

You have a really old servlet-api jar present in your project.

[`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse#getStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus--) was added in Servlet 3.0

Add the following:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Dump your dependencies and verify that you don't have multiple versions of the servlet-api jars present (this is common, as the maven coordinate space for the servlet-api jars have changed a few times over the past 10 years)

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was running tests with MockMvc. I was using `javax.servlet-api` in my library, which was a dependency in my microservice. I changed scope from `compile` to `provided`. Now it is working.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```