# No Such Method Error when Running JUnit Test

Tags: spring, rest, junit, mockito

When I try to run a JUnit class I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1083)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1009)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at com.springapp.app.filters.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:24)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at com.springapp.app.controllers.UserControllerUnitTest.test_get_by_id_fail_404_not_found(UserControllerUnitTest.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

I suspect it's a configuration problem in my POM.xml but I'm not sure. Here's the dependencies by the way:

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>       com.app
>       springapp
>       app
>       war
>       1.0.0
>       
>           1.8
>           5.0.3.RELEASE
>           1.6.10
>           1.6.6
>           5.0.5.Final
>           2.9.4
>           4.3.1.RELEASE
>       
>       
>           
>           
>               org.springframework
>               spring-context
>               ${org.springframework-version}
>               
>                   
>                   
>                       commons-logging
>                       commons-logging
>                   
>               
>           
>           
>               org.springframework
>               spring-webmvc
>               ${org.springframework-version}

```
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA 2.1 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Driver JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.42</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The problem could be that you are using an old version of servlet-api. You are using version 2.5.
Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44730174/3790546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [HttpServletResponse#getStatus](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus()) is available starts 3.0. so update your `servlet-api` to 3.0+, for example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```