# Jetty:run fails with NoSuchMethodError with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to update my web application to current libraries. When I upgraded Spring from 3.1.1 to 5.0.0 it started to fail with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
```

I have found two relevant questions:

- [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus() not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730096/javax-servlet-http-httpservletresponse-getstatus-not-found)
- [NoSuchMethodError while calling response.getStatus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257459/nosuchmethoderror-while-calling-response-getstatus)

which explained a lot and I have upgraded jetty and servlet spec. But my app keeps failing.

Dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
```

Maven:

```
    <spring.framework.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <maven-jetty-plugin.version>6.1.26</maven-jetty-plugin.version>
    <servlet.api.version>3.1.0</servlet.api.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<build>
    <finalName>smartpos-backend-device</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                <jettyEnvXml>src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                <contextPath>smartpos-json</contextPath>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>

                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
                        <value>logback.xml</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>LOG_PATH</name>
                        <value>.</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Spring 5 requires a servlet 3.1 or higher container, Jetty 6 is a 2.5 container. So it will simply not work you need to upgrade to the latest Jetty version. You will need to switch to the `jetty-maven-plugin` instead of the old `maven-jetty-plugin`.

Comment: Can you write it as answer? I can start it now without error. But I have to solve 404 for my servlet. RequestMappingHandlerMapping Mapped "{[/handshake],methods=[POST],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public void controller.DeviceJsonController.performHandShake(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring 5 requires a Servlet 3.1 container as a bare minimum however as you are using Jetty 6.1 which is (at most) a Servlet 2.5 container. So that is obviously not going to work.

You will have to upgrade your Jetty version. To upgrade instead of the `maven-jetty-plugin` you will need to use the appropriate `jetty-maven-plugin` (the name has changed) and it is part of Eclipse now.

```
<maven-jetty-plugin.version>9.4.7.v20170914</maven-jetty-plugin.version>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

This should use the latest version of both the plugin and thus Jetty.

Comment: Thanks. I have created new question for compatibility issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849304/spring-dispatcher-not-called-in-jetty-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

My bad I got it wrong. I think the problem is your jetty version:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/6.1.26

Here the servlet API is 2.5 and when you add dependency in Maven and mark it with provided scope it means the required JARs will be provided on a later stage and not packed with the war. So the code compiles properly in the IDE and development but when you try to run it with jetty it uses the actual servlet-api coming from the jetty version. And for that method you need servlet-api version 3 or above

Comment: compile error :-) package javax.servlet.http does not exist