# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I

Tags: spring, rest, servlets, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

This issue primarily happens due to some conflict of jar and same i have tried to checked, the servlet-api jar and updated with the latest one. Still issue in not resolved.

Getting this error

```
   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 Mar 11, 2018 9:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1083)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1009)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>www.crystal-techmax.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudentCrud</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StudentCrud Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <SpringVersion>5.0.4.RELEASE</SpringVersion>
        <spring.security.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.14.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <fasterxml.jackson.version>2.9.4</fasterxml.jackson.version>
        <servlet-api-version>4.0.0</servlet-api-version>
        <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${SpringVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring : Security dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate-4 dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--MYSQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet and JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Loggers API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>StudentCrud</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomact.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- yours Java version -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- yours Java version -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please let me know, if servlet-api or any other jar is complicating this issue, may be any jar still need to remove or add on the top of this

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, 
set the goal as tomcat:run in eclipse instead of tomcat7:run
when you add dependency in Maven and mark it with provided scope it means the required JARs will be provided on a later stage and not packed with the war. So the code compiles properly in the IDE and development but when you try to run it with tomcat it uses the actual servlet-api coming from the tomcat version. And for that method you need servlet-api version 3 or above.

[Jetty:run fails with NoSuchMethodError with Spring 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847578/jettyrun-fails-with-nosuchmethoderror-with-spring-5?noredirect=1&lq=1)